# How can I use gatsby-plugin-offline to create a completely offline version of my site? Automatically download all the pages, images, etc?

Tags: gatsby

I'm looking for some help. I want people to be able to go to my Gatsby website, click "Add to Home Screen", and then be able to browse the site completely offline.

I want to download the whole website (images, javascript, all the pages, everything) automatically, without users having to open each page for it to get cached.

I know that Gatsby has `gatsby-plugin-offline`, and it sounds like it should make this sort of thing possible, but I can't figure out how to configure it correctly. Just uncommenting the plugin didn't do the trick.

Can you help me find the correct config for accomplishing that?

Answer (score 0):

To use it like that, your website must be a Progressive Web App. To achieve this, your website need 3 things:

- Served over HTTPS
- Has Web App Manifest
- Has  service worker.

And it should have an appropriate icon to use it on your Home Screen

You should use [gatsby-plugin-manifest](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-manifest) for this. Further info on Gatsby's PWA [page](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/progressive-web-app/).